# Save certain number of bytes from a file into a specific memory adress

Tags: c

I have open a file and I know how to read the number of bytes that I want for it but now I want to save that bytes into a specific adress from memory and i dont know how I can do that.

The following code is what i have:

```
void fileSaver(char * n []){
    int fil;
    int bytes;
    char * space = malloc(100);

    fil= open("file",O_RDONLY);
    bytes=read(fil,space,4);

    printf("%d\n",bytes );
    printf("%s\n",space );


}
```

the n that I use as parameter for the function is the number of bytes that I want to read